# Authorize redirect 401 not working

Tags: redirect, cookies, browser, asp.net-core, authorization

I have an implementation in .net-core using cookieauthentication.

However, i am experiencing the following issue:
When accessing a page when I am not logget in and where the AuthorizationAttribute is set, it just shows me a blank page, instead of redirecting me to the login page.

Fiddler tells me that I am receiving a 401 unauthorized response. The Location Header is set to /Home, but is ignored by the browser, since the status code is 401.

The cookie implementation looks like this:

```
          app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Home"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/logout"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/accessdenied")
        });
```

AuthorizationAttribute works fine, since I can access the page as soon as I am logged in.

From my understanding, the AutomaticChallenge = true should take care of this. Is this wrong?

Comment: It's pretty strange. May be something else in your pipeline change 302 redirect http status code to 401.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing issue with AutomaticChallenge option. This option is causing a conflict between IISIntegration and Cookie middleware, see detailed notes [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/210).

If you are using [Authorize], the solution would be to add the following code to your startup.cs inside `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("Cookies").RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
});
```

I tested it and it works!

Comment: I have added the code snippet, but for me it doesn't work. No difference to what happens. Note that I am using Kestrel.

Comment: How about specifying AuthenticationScheme in [Authorize]? [Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

Comment: Bingo! Specifying: [Authorize]: [Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] did the trick! Thank you so much